# NSNumberFormatter and rounding percentage value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

here is my code snip, i dont know how to round double numbers.

```
double m =  [tmpProduct.msrp doubleValue] ;
double d = [tmpProduct.discountPrice doubleValue];
double p = (d * 100 ) / m;
```

here tmpProduct.msrp and mpProduct.discountPrice are (NSDecimalNUmber *)

from the operation above I got p = 44.995757

i want to convert it to (45%) , how do i do that?

here is what i use , but that does not help.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:p]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the arithmetic operations NSDecimalNumber provides?
I haven't tried that myself, but it seems you are bypassing the advantages of NSDecimalNumber by using standard operators ( *, /, ...) on the double values of your number instances.
Take a look at [NSDecimalNumber: Performing Arithmetic](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000179-DontLinkElementID_6)

As Objective-C does not support operator overloading you will have to use methods such as:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByDividingBy:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
```

**Update:**
Division using NSDecimalNumber:

```
NSDecimalNumber* operandOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1234.5"];
NSDecimalNumber* operandTwo = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2335"];
NSDecimalNumber* result = [operandOne decimalNumberByDividingBy:operandTwo];
NSLog(@"%@", [result descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
```

by using `descriptionWithLocale:` , you get the correct `NSLocaleDecimalSeparator`

**Update 2:**
I forgot about the rounding:
NSDecimalNumber supports several rounding modes.
Read the documentation of [`decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:)

Comment: thanks for reply.i tried this 
NSDecimalNumber *d1 = [tmpProduct.discountPrice decimalNumberByDividingBy:tmpProduct.msrp];
but that give me exception ( here is values i got discounprice = 1234.5 and masrp is 2335)

Comment: I updated my answer with a small example, that uses the values you pasted. Works fine here. Maybe you can post more details? Do you use Core Data/bindings etc...?

Comment: thanks for reply.here is more detail.
i am getting values for tmpProduct.DiscountedPrice and tmpProduct.msrp as in json formate, and i use TouchJson to parse.

self.msrp =[aDictionary valueForKey:kMSRP];
self.discountPrice =[aDictionary valueForKey:kDiscountPrice];
when i tried this 
NSDecimalNumber *d1 = [tmpProduct.discountPrice decimalNumberByDividingBy:tmpProduct.discountPrice];
it gives me exception? so i am wondering is it original data issue that i am getting from TouchJson? why can i use my tmp.DiscountedPrice w/o converting it again as you said? and i dont use any core data..

Comment: i found out problem. it was data problem. now i am getting price as string like "2500.00" and than i am converting like this 
<pre><code>
[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[aDictionary valueForKey:kDiscountPrice]"];
</code></pre>

But my orginal problem is still there if i have percentage = 45.72, it should get rounded to 46% , or if its 44.32 then 44%?

Comment: As you are dealing with prices and currencies, I would take the NSDecimalNumber route. I just updated my original answer with a link to the "Rounding Off" section of Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, I'd suggest setting the style to NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle and the maximum fraction digits to 0.  Then you shouldn't have to worry about the rounding.  This works for me:

```
double p = d / m;  // note: not multiplying by 100 here

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
NSString *s = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:p]];
```

This gives the string "45%".